# Mute/Unmute video's Audio progressively

Tags: javascript

with this code I can toggle mute/unmute a playing video's Audio:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('mute'),
      video = document.querySelector('video');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (btn.value === 'unmuted') {
    btn.value = 'muted';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i>';
    video.muted = true;
  } else {
    btn.value = 'unmuted';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>';
    video.muted = false;
  }
});

<a id="mute" value="muted"><i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i></a>
```

How could I add a fadeIn/fadeOut Audio effect when the button is clicked instead of instant mute/unmute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use JQuery .animate to fade in/out from the video. The animated volume is in double (between 0 to 1)

```js
var $video_player = $('#video-player');
var $mute_button = $('#mute-button');

$mute_button.on('click', () => {
   
   $video_player.toggleClass('mute');
   
   if ($video_player.hasClass('mute')) {
    // Fade out audio
    $video_player.animate({ volume: 0 }, 5000);
    $mute_button.html('unmute');
   } else {
    // Fade in audio
    $video_player.animate({ volume: 1 }, 5000);
    $mute_button.html('mute');
   }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="video-player" width="100%" height="150px" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<center><button id="mute-button">mute</button></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are not using jQuery, so here's a vanilla JavaScript solution for you. It is not practical to import a huge library just for one simple functionality.

It is actually not hard to make a fade effect without any libraries. All you need is:

1. A loop or [animation frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).
2. An easing function.

You can see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294) for a list of easing function to use.

For the example below, I use "easeInOutCubic":

```
const btn = document.getElementById('mute'),
      video = document.querySelector('video');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (btn.value === 'unmuted') {
    btn.value = 'muted';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i>';
    muteVideo(true);
  } else {
    btn.value = 'unmuted';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>';
    muteVideo(false);
  }
});

function muteVideo(bool){
  // Set fade speed.
  // The lower the speed, the slower the fade.
  const speed = 0.00025;

  // Get video initial volume.
  const i = video.volume;

  // If true, fade out
  // else, fade in
  if (bool === true){

    for (; i >= 0; i -= speed){
      video.volume = easeInOutCubic(i);
    }

  } else {

    for (; i <= 1; i += speed){
      video.volume = easeInOutCubic(i);
    }

  }
}

// See https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
function easeInOutCubic(t){
  return t < 0.5
    ? 4*t*t*t
    : (t - 1)*(2*t - 2)*(2*t - 2) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunatelly, I'm not able to reproduce it, it doesn't fadein nor fadeout the audio.

Comment: @cdxJava can you update in your question what have you tried?